# Program to 'Change color of a circle on click doesn't Compile

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compiler-errors, event-handling

I'm Learning GUI in  Java from "Head First Java"
When I wrote the following Program I can't figure out where I have gone wrong even after 
debugging for over 20 minutes .

```
import javax.swing.*;//for the frame etc
import java.awt.*;//for  paintComponent(),Grapics Object etc
import java.awt.event.*;//for listeners


//display a circle and chang eits color when a button is clicked

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel//this class will contain code for the circle
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
    int r=(int)(Math.random()*255);//generate random float between 0 & 255
    int b=(int)(Math.random()*255);//generate random float between 0 & 255
    int gr=(int)(Math.random()*255);//generate random float between 0 & 255
    Color randcolor=new Color(r,gr,b);//name clashed with Graphics g
    g.setColor(randcolor);
    g.fillOval(90,90,120,120);//default background color is used,oval is filled with Color (randcolor);
    }
}

public class changecolor implements ActionListener
{

JButton button;//ie this class's objects have a button as an instance field
MyDrawPanel p;//similar except this isuser defined

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    changecolor c=new changecolor();
    c.go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
    button=new JButton("Change Color ");
    button.addActionListener(this);//this class ie object of this class listens to                       the action
    p=new MyDrawPanel();
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(700,700);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTRE,p);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    frame.repaint();//repaint or referesh the frame;

    }


}
```

I get these Errors

```
  changecolor.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    frame.repaint();//repaint or referesh the frame;
    ^
  symbol:   variable frame
  location: class changecolor
1 error
```

I know i missed something trivial ,can someone please tell me what I missed ?, Thanks you !.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java a public class must be written in a file named like this class. In this case you need two files: **MyDrawPanel.java** and **changecolor.java**

Comment: oh thanks I changed it , now it just says repaint() cant be found , I have edited my question, Please check it out now.

Comment: I figured it out , JFrame frame is declared as a local varaible in main() and action Performed cant access it , i'll change it

Comment: In your function **actionPerformed** you are using the variable ***frame*** which is declared in the go method. Define frame aß class variable, just below MyDrawPanel p;